# different pdf views on different softwares: vs studio code, chrome and acrobat reader, after imagemagick tif -> pdf convertion

Tags: google-chrome, pdf, visual-studio-code, imagemagick, tiff

I'm converting a tif file to pdf with imagemagick:

**Imagemagick version:** `7.1.0-13`

**Imagemagick command:** `magick convert -density 80 -page a4 -limit map 3GB -limit memory 3GB tiff:- pdf:-`

This has been working good until meeting this guy:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1AJjN8F2RoKViE56ZE7I9XDYTJ-HefUaA/view

Which converted it to this pdf:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1C3Dfd7fGvgJFqJwKbOoLPB-om80gc3PP/view

Now if you view the result on a browser, like chrome, you see multiple empty pages:
[image]

However opening the file with adobe reader I get this instead:

[image]

And what it's weird, with vs studio, the file looks good:
[image]

For viewing the pdf on visual studio I'm using this extension:
[image]

Now the question is, how do I fix this?

[edited]
Even after upgrading the library it doesn't work, maybe missing dependency?
OP: debian

DockerFile building the image:

```
FROM debian
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
RUN apt-get update -qq &&\
  apt-get install -y -qq \
  chrpath debhelper dh-exec dpkg-dev g++ ghostscript gsfonts libbz2-dev \
  libdjvulibre-dev libexif-dev libfftw3-dev libfontconfig1-dev libfreetype6-dev \
  libjpeg-dev liblcms2-dev liblqr-1-0-dev libltdl-dev liblzma-dev libopenexr-dev \
  libpango1.0-dev libperl-dev libpng-dev librsvg2-bin librsvg2-dev libtiff-dev libwebp-dev \
  libwmf-dev libx11-dev libxext-dev libxml2-dev libxt-dev pkg-config pkg-kde-tools zlib1g-dev
RUN apt-get install wget 
# Install ImageMagick Platform-independent build dependencies
RUN apt-get update -qq &&\
  apt-get install -y -qq \
  doxygen doxygen-latex graphviz jdupes libxml2-utils xsltproc
# Install and Configure ImageMagick
RUN wget https://github.com/ImageMagick/ImageMagick/archive/refs/tags/7.1.0-28.tar.gz -P /opt
RUN tar xvf /opt/7.1.0-28.tar.gz -C /opt
RUN /opt/ImageMagick-7.1.0-28/configure --with-modules --enable-shared
RUN make -j 2 /opt/ImageMagick-7.1.0-28
RUN make install /opt/ImageMagick-7.1.0-28/
RUN make distclean
RUN ldconfig /usr/local/lib
RUN rm /opt/7.1.0-28.tar.gz
```

[edited 2]
libtiff version: 4.2.0-1
[image]

Comment: The data in the PDF is inconsistent: on one hand the image is declared as using a 3 component color space with **DeviceRGB** as alternative, on the other hand the embedded ICC profile is **GRAY**, i.e. single component. Thus, depending on which information one uses, the data is interpreted differently.

Comment: do you think it could be a dependency or imagemagick itself?

Comment: @KJ  1) The pdf should be able to be viewed perfect on any software 2)the file is indeed available but on tif format, I need it on pdf for programming purposes, not the case itself

Comment: But what about the version of libtiff?

Comment: @John *"do you think it could be a dependency or imagemagick itself?"* - I don't know. Actually the next thing to do would be inspecting the tiff file internals to check whether already the color space information there is inconsistent. I'm not an expert of tiff, though, and i also don't have tiff tools ready, so i cannot quickly do that. But if the inconsistency already is in the tiff file, we simply have a case of GIGO, *garbage in, garbage out*.

Comment: @fmw42 libtiff-dev version is  4.2.0-1, I added it to edited part

Comment: I do not know much more other than it works for me using LIBTIFF, Version 4.3.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was ImageMagick's bug.
They fixed it on the new version https://github.com/ImageMagick/ImageMagick/issues/5256#event-6929844600

Answer (score 1):

In IM 7, use magick not magick convert. Add +repage after reading the TIFF

```
magick input2.tif[0] +repage -density 80 -page a4 input2.pdf
```

works fine for me on IM 7.1.0.28 Q16 Mac OSX Sierra.

Comment: it's not working on debian, I'm using a docker file to build imagemagick please see the edited part

Comment: Sorry, I do not use/know Docker. But is Imagemagick current and do you have all the delegates up to data, esp, libtiff?

Comment: yes I have, if you see the 3 line on docker file, you will see the libraries being installed, take docker as bash comands,  just ignore the first keywork